# oauth2.0 implemenation for providers

Tags: oauth, jersey, oltu

Can anyone help me with examples of OAuth implementation for providers. I have a sample web application and I want to provide Oauth to other clients for this application.
Any help would be appreciated.
I am currently using this example as a sample but my HttpServeletRequest shows null

http://blogs.steeplesoft.com/posts/2013/07/11/a-simple-oauth2-client-and-server-example-part-i/

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

You can find some in "[Libraries, Products, and Tools](http://openid.net/developers/libraries/)" page of [OpenID Connect website](http://openid.net/connect/). Loosely speaking, in the context of OpenID Connect, Identity Provider is OAuth Provider. So, solutions marked as "Identity Provider: Yes" in the page are OAuth Providers.

If you don't mind delegating the "authorization" part to an external server ([Authlete](https://www.authlete.com/)), source code examples of OAuth provider can be found at GitHub.

- authlete/[java-oauth-server](https://github.com/authlete/java-oauth-server)

Detailed generic information about what developers have to do to implement OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect can be found in [Authlete Definitive Guide](https://www.authlete.com/authlete_definitive_guide.html).